# Xpath: Need to select an xpath with changing div but same text

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to use browser.find_element to select a 9:00 PM timeslot on this booking website.

Depending on the week the xpath for the 9:00 PM timeslot may be:

`/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/div[13]`

OR

`/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/div[14]`

The variable div (13 or 14 above) is as follows, which contains a div with 9:00 pm.

```html
<div class="timeslot odd" style="height: 133px; cursor: pointer; width: 145px;" xpath="1">

<div class="time"> 9:00 pm</div>

</div>
```

How can I specify the xpath in a way that will always reference the 9:00 pm timeslot.

I tried this but it did not work:

`browser.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/div[contains(text(), "9:00 pm")])')`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Pls post the URL.

Comment: you need give the whole web page html, or give the link

Comment: Since there is no page url, it is difficult to understand what you have there, but you can try: //div[@class="time"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below xpath -

```
//div[contains(@class,'timeslot')]/div[contains(text(),'9:00 pm')]
```